# Is Mega Man left or right handed?

Tags: mega-man-series

One question I ask myself since I am a kid:
Is Mega Man left or right handed?

(I am confused each time he turns left or right)

**UPDATE:** I am adding a bounty for whoever finds me some official press release documents or interviews showing that the character designers of Mega Man wanted him to be left handed, right handed, or .. both at the same time.

Comment: Are you referring to which hand his buster is in?

Comment: More seriously, I am referring to what Capcom wanted him to be. Some characters are designed to be left handed or right handed. For example, Link in the Zelda games is left handed.

Comment: Tough question. Traditionally Mega Man's buster is in his left hand -  but that doesn't mean he's left handed.

Comment: You made me laugh. This question is so fantastic. Thankyou.

Comment: @Wipqozn > Well, if his buster is in his left hand, I would assume that makes him right-handed.  Since the right hand is the only one he'll be able to use for anything else.

Comment: I heard a rumor long ago that the developers had always intended a gun to pop out of megaman and X's arms, but due to the nature of the sprites, a seam was missing, and so it appeared that his arm turned into a gun, instead of a gun appearing in his hand. Take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: I think his dominant hand is determined by whatever the devs felt like when they sat down to make a given game in the series.

Comment: @GnomeSlice You can't just assume that though - in could be his left hand so he can aim with the buster better. Also, "  
 
I think his dominant hand is determined by whatever the devs felt like when they sat down to make a given game in the series"   I agree - with the possible exception of megamans creator, I doubt anyone at Capcom really cares

Comment: Given that OP raises a bounty specifically asking for proof in what the original creators were wanting, I am voting to close this question as a request for Developer Intent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, after looking at official box art, Megaman uses either hand for his arm cannon. For example, here's some Japanese promo art from Megaman 3 depicting the cannon on his left arm.

[image: Left arm cannon Megaman]

While here's some Japanese promo art from Megaman 2 depicting the cannon on his right arm instead.

[image: Right arm cannon Megaman]

If you check more of the images and box art, there's no real rhyme or reason as to which hand the arm cannon appears on. So, since he uses either hand just as often in the images and in the games, the only conclusion I can draw from this is that he is indeed ambidextrous.

Comment: That's quite a good argument.

Comment: As additional evidence for ambidexterity, Zero, a similar robot to Mega Man, is clearly depicted as ambidextrous, often wielding a weapon in each hand or a buster in one hand and a sword in the other (official art often using different hands for each weapon)

Answer (score 17):

Well... the original Megaman had his buster on his left, and X on the right.

> (I am confused each time he turns left or right)

Well, this happens because when the Megaman sprite turns, the entire sprite image is flipped horizontally, meaning depending on which way you're facing, Megaman's buster will be on different hands. [This](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AmbidextrousSprite) page can tell a bit more of what I just said, though it isn't exactly an informative site : /

But being a robot/android/Navi, I really think Megaman is programmed to be ambidextrous.

Comment: I was kidding when I wrote I was confused. I wrote it because this website didn't accept a question too short. Sorry. Still, you got my +1 for the first line, a fact that I didn't know.

Comment: Where have you seen the information about that first line? The boxart for Megaman X shows the buster on his left arm, while the japanese boxart for Rockman 2 shows the buster on his right arm.

Comment: Actually Megaman X had his buster on the left too... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvFd8sJfwsg&feature=related

Comment: @Wipqozn: Not necessarily.  The sprites are made so the "background arm" has the megabuster.  Go to ~2:30 in that video and you'll see that he becomes righty again.

Comment: Most of the concept art I've seen has him using his buster with his left hand, and X using his right. But I think that since he morphs his hands to be the buster he could probably use either. Him being a robot I can't imagine anything that would give him better aim with one over the other besides how he is positioned at the moment.

Comment: Nice answer. For anyone wanting to know more about how the NES sprite pattern tables worked, [this page](https://www.dustmop.io/blog/2015/06/08/nes-graphics-part-2/) has some details - with Megaman examples too!

Answer (score 8):

In *Megaman Legends* (and/or *Megaman 64*), Megaman's buster is on his left hand.  Since the game is three dimensional, there's no 'sprite flipping' like in the original sidescrollers.  This would mean that he is right-handed, at least in this game, because that's the only hand he has free when a weapon is equipped.

Comment: Is Legends considered part of the Megaman franchise? (As in, Megaman 1-10; clearly, X, .exe, zero, and ZX are different franchises)

Comment: @Raven I'm not sure.  Many people don't consider it as such.  I think it's supposed to be separate.  But the OP never stated which Megaman he was wondering about. ;)

Comment: In the effort of completeness, I think I left out Starforce, the successor to .exe (officially battle network)

Comment: @Raven Yes. It's at the very end of the timeline. It goes. 1-8 > X > Zero > ZX > Legends.

The Battle Network / Starforce timeline is AU. If you pay attention to the developments near the end of each series you can see the transition points into the next series. In Megaman 8 Zero is shown, at the end of X, Zero is lost, where he is refound in zero, the satellite event in Zero leads to the biometals in ZX and by the time of legends there aren't any people just biometal based humanoids.

Comment: Keiji Inafune wanted the series to continue with a 3rd legends game, But Capcom wasn't having it until recently.

Comment: Also also, X4 was supposed to be the last game in the X series, where Zero goes into hibernation to remove the sigma virus (to be refound much later by Ciel in Megaman Zero). I'm a little muddy on what happened after that, but that's where it was supposed to split.

Comment: You can't just assume he's right handed just because his buster is in his left hand... the buster could be in his left hand because he's left handed, and as such would have better aim. He could also be ambidextrous.

Comment: I am left handed, and when I point something with the finger, a wiimote, etc ... I instinctively use my left hand. Link was designed to be left handed and he is using his left hand to hit enemies with his sword.

I agree Wipqozn.

Comment: @Wipqozn > I think that the need to be able to manipulate objects finely with the free hand would outweigh this concern.

Comment: @GnomeSlice But it could be more important for him to be able to aim -  and either way, it could still mean he was ambidextrous.

Comment: @Wipqozn > Well, actually, considering that he's a machine (Reploid), he probably *is* ambidextrous.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Agreed - I don't think it would make any sense for him to not be ambidextrous.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out it's ambidextrous.  In [SuperAdventure Rockman](http://www.crunkgames.com/?p=34), he turns both hands into blasters at the same time - the 'Double Rock Buster' special move in Episode 3.  Granted, it almost kills him because it uses so much energy, but there it is anyway.

This means that the 'flipping' in the sidescrollers is just him switching hands.

Also, SuperAdventure Rockman can be pointed to as a 'shark-jumping' moment for Megaman.

Comment: Interesting, but to take 2 weapons at the same time doesn't imply that you are ambidextrous. Proof: I can take 1 Wiimote in each hand, and I am left handed.

Comment: But, consider that this shows both arms contain blasters, and to use both to the same level simultaneously would require ambidexterity - at the very least the same power level in each arm, which would imply the same conclusion.

Comment: I do not agree this logic. When I do push-ups, I use both arms with equal strength (because required by physic laws if I want to keep a good balance). Still, I am left handed.

Comment: But it's not a push-up or anything resistance-based (like a punch, etc), it's a shooting attack.  The physics are completely different.  Anyone and their brother can do a pushup, but almost no one can shoot two .44 magnums simultaneously and hit the same target.  You can take a Wiimote in each hand, but can you use them both with same degree of skill?  Nope.

Answer (score 4):

On many box arts and title screens, the buster is on his right arm, but in some it is on his left arm or in none of them. So, one can assume that he "morphs" his arm into a buster, and that he may do that with either of the arms, depending on how clear a shot would be in each case. I agree with Oscar Cheung, Megaman is probably ambidextrous.

Comment: In X3 at least, X gains the ability to fire charged buster shots from each arm sequentially. It's pretty awesome.

Comment: You might be right. Now I don't know which answer to choose as the correct one. Difficult choice !

Answer (score 3):

I generally depend on which hand is used for gulping energy tanks, writing, and for special weapons that involve throwing (blades, boomerangs) or melee (claws, sabers) as the dominant hand, especially if all four of those are with the same hand.  Furthermore, making that dominant hand vanish to make room for a buster (to me) sounds rather inconvenient.  I would thus place the buster **opposite** from the dominant hand, for the sake of convenience.  Especially in the case of Zero, since he is a melee combatant.  If I remember correctly, Zero switched his melee combat from righty to lefty upon operating a new vessel.  I'm not sure, since some sources say vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Super Smash Bros. for Wii U and 3DS, whenever Mega Man turns around the buster changes hands. Also, he has a taunt where he transforms an arm into the buster and back. Depending on which way you face when you do it, he can turn both arms into Mega Busters. So, logically, he is ambidextrous.

Answer (score 0):

Most people have covered the answer by now (he's an ambidextrous, which makes sense, because he's a *robot*.... why program something limiting like right or left-handedness? He's a SUPER FIGHTING ROBOT, he don't have time for that!)

Just wanted to add another source for that answer: The Megaman TV show. Anime/style aside, he often transforms either hand into the Megabuster (or whatever weapon he has "equipped"), as needed. He and Roll both can use both arms as weapons and are presumably ambidextrous.

Answer (score -1):

http://megaman.wikia.com/wiki/Mega_Buster

He is the best in the world and can use both hands.
He is ambidextrous.

Answer (score -1):

Let's start this by referencing box art nobody wants to remember. [image: Rockman]

Our vaguely-Indo-Chinese billowy-armed Blue Bomber with frog legs appears left handed, as he's holding the weapon (a pistol, not the Buster Cannon) in his left hand.  The pistol itself seems to be a traditional firearm, not an energy-based weapon.  We also know that the arm cannon was something Dr. Light developed, using Solar shots [(the many iterations of the Buster Cannon)](http://megaman.wikia.com/wiki/Mega_Buster).  This suggests the pistol image below references a time *before* Light made the cannon, indicating handedness.  The Buster weapon itself is referenced as ambidextrous, but not the robot; this is similar to how a baseball bat is ambidextrous in nature, but handedness determines the swing.   The pre-Buster pistol in the image is certainly *not* such a weapon, as while held in the left hand we have to infer that shells would eject out of the unseen side of the pistol (as no slide or ejection port is visible).  This would make the gun itself a right-handed weapon, held by a left-handed person.

Following the art on the same page, we can see that standalone images of the various Mega Man incarnations begin to show the Buster on the left arm repeatedly.  One could arguably say that the more plot in your Mega Man, the more right-handed he gets.  There's a trope involved here; [A Sinister Clue](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ASinisterClue).  For literally centuries, entertainment has placed the villain or the goofball as being left-handed.  Even in modern movies, while the "main character" might be left-handed, it's actually a clue that the one character who is right-handed is the real hero of the story.  This actually fits in with Mega Man's Lore, as from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Man) entry, Mega Man was originally a battle robot made by BOTH Dr.'s Wily and Light.  It goes on to say that Mega Man (originally named "Rock") was refitted *after* being a villainous battle robot:

> "Following treachery by Dr. Wily in which he reprogrammed all of Dr
>   Light's robots, Rock was converted into a battle robot to defend the
>   world from Wily's violent robotic threats. Thus he becomes Mega Man."

This suggests that while the weapons he uses are ambidextrous, Mega Man actually started out left-handed and literally had his handedness changed for story purposes to match with Western culture's expectations and tropes.  All because ugly-halfway-racist-proto-MegaMan pictured in the box art would have held a right-handed weapon in the right hand if he were ambidextrous or right handed, as the ejecting shells across the chest of a traditional firearm (as pictured) would risk damage and not fit with machine logic. He technically was born as a villain, so we see him with a gun in his left hand before Light ever modified him.

Edit: [image] Captain N's Megaman doesn't count.  Green with wrist launchers and toddler-sized.  No.

Comment: ... I don't think Wikipedia is a reputable source. Check the wiki, it actually has reference to official material. Wily didn't even consider Rock & Roll as worthy targets when he first reprogrammed the original 6 robot masters. Also, I wouldn't consider the usa box art canon - if you did you would have to consider [the back of the box canon too....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozE31.jpg). "Megaman must penetrate the seven separate societies of Dr Wily.". Yeah, right, they described the real story 100%.